# Retorno de verificação é enviada três vezes

Tags: jquery

Ao clicar no botão, executa esse código a baixo

Ele era gerar apenas uma posição do array. No caso é gerado 3 posições, como se houvesse acontecido 3 testes

```
$(document).on('click','#btnSegundaEtapa',function () {

    var arrayObjCat1 = [];

    $(".form-group").find('*').each(function(){
        var id = $(this).attr("id");

        if($(this).is(':checked')){
            if ( $("input[type='radio'][name='Licenciamentodeusuários']").is(':checked') ) {
                className = $("#"+id).data('class-name');
                vlrUnitario = $("."+className).text();

                vlrUnitario = vlrUnitario.replace("$","");
                vlrUnitario = parseFloat(vlrUnitario.replace(',','.'));
                arrayObjCat1.push({part_number:$('#'+id).data('part-number'), nome_item:$('#'+id).data('nome-item'),qtde:$('#'+id).val(),preco_unitario:vlrUnitario});
                console.log(arrayObjCat1);
            }


         }
     })

});
```

E acontece esse retorno
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Considere explicar melhos seu problema

Comment: apertei para publicar sem querer, olha se ficou mais claro

Comment: Gabriel, qual é a pergunta ou o que não está a funcionar como queres?

Comment: Eu quero que esse dado só seja executado 1 vez e não as 3 vezes

Comment: Você está executando `console.log` dentro da função `each`, isso quer dizer que irá imprimir no console cada vez que passar pelo loop. Experimente colocar o console fora do loop que irá imprimir apenas uma vez.

Comment: Tens `$(".form-group").find('*').each(` isso vai fazer o código correr várias vezes...

Comment: Mas ele gera um array de 3 posições, isso que não quero

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('click','#btnSegundaEtapa',function () {

    var arrayObjCat1 = [];

    $(".form-group").find('*').each(function(){
        var id = $(this).attr("id");

        if($(this).is(':checked')){
            if ( $("input[type='radio'][name='"+id+"']").is(':checked') ) {
                className = $("#"+id).data('class-name');
                vlrUnitario = $("."+className).text();

                vlrUnitario = vlrUnitario.replace("$","");
                vlrUnitario = parseFloat(vlrUnitario.replace(',','.'));
                arrayObjCat1.push({part_number:$('#'+id).data('part-number'), nome_item:$('#'+id).data('nome-item'),qtde:$('#'+id).val(),preco_unitario:vlrUnitario});
                console.log(arrayObjCat1);
            }


         }
     })

});
```

o codigo acima solucionou meu problema